# Unable to add assembly reference for windows phone app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, assemblies

I am trying to create a background task in Windows phone application. However I am unable to add reference to Windows.ApplicationModel.Background dll. Where is it located and how to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a part of the Windows Phone platform, it is part of the Windows Store platform.

[MSDN - Windows.ApplicationModel.Background namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224847)